# Why are objects not cleaned as soon as they are out of scope?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

In .net why does Garbage collector not destroy objects the moment they are out of scope? Why does it wait until the next clean up process runs?

Comment: There is a nice article on understanding the .Net garbage collector here: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was tried, a project undertaken by Chris Sells and Chris Tavares back in the fall of 2003, sponsored by Microsoft.  They modified the CLR (Rotor edition) by adding a reference count field to every object and by modifying the JIT compiler to automatically decrement the count when a reference goes out of scope.  And automatically running the finalizer when the count goes to zero.

The goal was achieved, no longer any need for the *using* statement.

Operation successful, patient dead however.  The modifications caused a severe performance degradation.  They tried to diagnose it, calling in the help of Compuware, at the time a leading tool vendor.  But could not nail it down.  The blog post that published the failure [is here](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/Posts/Details/1141), the technical details [are here](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/refcount_rotor.doc).

The garbage collector got a lot more respect after this.  No further attempts have been made since then that I know of.

Answer (score 3):

That would require a reference-counting form of GC. The .NET GC is of the [mark-and-sweep](http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node47.html) type.

Objects do not go out of scope. The references to the objects do. And the compiler could easily track that, but are there any other references to the same object? That is not so trivial.

Reference counting has 2 major problems:

1. the compiler has to generate extra code every time a reference is passed, copied or dropped
2. When two objects refer to each other you have a memory leak.

Comment: Suppose you declare an instance variable department d1=new department(); Now once d1 is out of scope, which ever memory location d1 was pointing to is not accessible anymore. Can you give me a scenario where that is not true?

Comment: Suppose the constructor `new Department()` registers itself in a static list.

Comment: @user1110437 how about "return d1;"

Comment: @user1110437 Suppose 4 threads all have references to the same object that they're passing to functions. Do you really want to have to serialize the increment/decrement of a single reference count each time? (Think about the horrible cache ping-ponging on a modern multi-core CPU. Yuck.)

Answer (score 0):

The app/system might be busy doing other things.  Thus, an immediate GC run might cause a performance hit.  The system tries to determine the best time to run the GC.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not process, but thread.

The main reason is for performance: the process of garbage collecting is expensive, thus the "virtual machine" prefers to leave some memory "astray" (well, not really: it can still reference it) and allocate memory for new objects when needed. It will still run regularly, though, because leaving memory astray for too long doesn't do any good either.

Garbage collecting algorithms are plenty: see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). The intent of a garbage collection algorithm is to vampire as little time as possible from running code. Garbage collecting immediately after objects get out of scope does not really fit that bill...

Answer (score 0):

Because then you'd need checks every time any reference (object member, variable, collection item, etc.) is assigned/changed. And you'd need to keep track of all references to an object, e.g. by storing the count and keeping it up-to-date. This is called reference counting and has numerous issues, from general performance (each reference assignment requires comparisions and memory access) to synchronization overhead in the presence of concurrency (what happens if two threads juggle references to the same object at the same time?) to the inability to detect cycles (if A refers to B and B refers to A, neither reference count can drop to 0, so you leak memory or you still need a "full" GC as described below).

Instead, most garbage collectors just let references come and go, and if they need to collect, they follow the references that currently exist to determine which objects are in use (respectively, *could* be in use as they are reachable) and deallocate the rest. Obviously, this is a lot of work, so you only do it once in a while. There are some more refined approaches which minimize the work per average collection or prefer to collect regions of the heap that are more likely. But the general problem remains: You can't find all garbage as soon as it becomes garbage, as that would mean walking the whole heap every time a reference changes.